# Merge overlaping rectangles in python

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

I have a list of rectangular coordinates and some of them are overlapping but I don't know which. I want to merge the overlapping coordinate with some threshold. How I can do it in python (is there any function available in OpenCV?)?. I am using OpenCV to generate the rectangles using `cv2.findContours()`

I want to do something like [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/11/17/non-maximum-suppression-object-detection-python/) but for that, I need a cluster of overlapping rectangles and I am not sure which are overlapping.

Comment: what exact you want to achieve? is it face detection or anything else?

Comment: something similar to rectangles in object detection.